# Logstash - One Input - Multiple output

Tags: logstash

I have a file contains many json objects as following:

> { "Browser": "Chrome", "Version": "45.0.2454.99", "Plugins": [ {
>   "Plugin": "Flash", "Version": "11.2.4.3"  }, { "Plugin": "Firebug", "Version": "1.5.6.0" } ], "Storages":
>   [ { "Storage": "LS", "Time": 106 }, { "Storage": "WS", "Time": 167 } ]
>   }

Is it possible to create three following indexes in logstash?

- browser-indexes: Browser, Version
- plugin-indexes: Plugin, Version
- storage-indexes: Storage, Time

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. At a high-level, the following approach could be used:

1. Use [clone](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-clone.html) to create multiple copies of the input data.
2. Clone will add a 'type' to each copy, which you can then use to process different copies of the documents with different filters.
3. In the output definition, add if/else statements to detect the 'type', and use this to direct different copies of the documents to different outputs.

My [blog post](https://alexmarquardt.com/2018/08/31/using-logstash-to-drive-filtered-data-from-a-single-source-into-multiple-output-destinations/) demonstrates the above steps, with few additional enhancements.

Another possible approach would be to use [pipeline-to-pipeline communication (beta)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html)

Disclaimer: I am a Consulting Engineer at Elastic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but it would take some work.

You would need to clone{} each event, remove the fields from the clone that you didn't want in that copy (see prune{}), and then direct each clone to a separate output{} stanza.

Now, the real question is 'why'?  Unless you have some security or data retention issue that requires this, I'd recommend against it.